# How can I implement wait_for_page_to_load in Selenium 2?

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

I am new to automated web testing and I am currently migrating from an old Selenium RC implementation to Selenium 2 in Ruby. Is there a way to halt the execution of commands until the page gets loaded, similar to "`wait_for_page_to_load`" in Selenium RC?

Comment: Not a complete answer but see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_WebDriver_fails_to_find_elements_/_Does_not_block_on_page_loa for a bit of discussion.

Comment: I have already tried "wait" but that is not working I seems the issue is only there on windows machine, test case are working fine on linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Javascript to inform you!

I created a couple methods that checks via our javascript libraries and waits to see if the page has finished loading the DOM and that all ajax requests are complete. Here's a sample snippet. The javascript you will need to use is just going to depend on your library.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 30).until { @driver.execute_script("[use javascript to return true once loaded, false if not]"}
```

I then wrapped these methods in a `clickAndWait` method that clicks the element and calls the waitForDomLoad and waitForAjaxComplete. Just for good measure, the very next command after a clickAndWait is usually a `waitForVisble` element command to ensure that we are on the right page.

```
# Click element and wait for page elements, ajax to complete, and then run whatever else
def clickElementAndWait(type, selector)
    @url = @driver.current_url
    clickElement(type, selector)
    # If the page changed to a different URL, wait for DOM to complete loading
    if @driver.current_url != @url
      waitForDomLoad
    end
    waitForAjaxComplete
    if block_given?
      yield
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I fixed a lot of issues I was having in that department adding this line after starting my driver

```
driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 20
```

This basically makes every failed driver call you make retry for maximum 20 seconds before throwing an exception, which is usually enough time for your AJAX to finish.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `capybara`, whenever you are testing for `page.should have_content("foo")`, capybara will not fail instantly if the page doesn't have the content (yet) but will wait for a while to see if an ajax call will change that.

So basically: after you `click`, you want to check right away for `have_content("some content that is a consequence of that click")`.

Comment: I am not using capybara. I am using only webdriver.