# selenium-webdriver and wait for page to load

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to write simple test. My problem is, that i want to wait until the page is loaded completly. At the moment i'm waiting until some elements are presen, but that is not really what i want. Is it possible to make something like this:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.navigate.to url
driver.wait_for_page_to_load "30000"
```

With Java isn't problem, but how to make it with ruby?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is how the [Selenium docs](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example) () suggest:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get "http://google.com"

element = driver.find_element :name => "q"
element.send_keys "Cheese!"
element.submit

puts "Page title is #{driver.title}"

wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
wait.until { driver.title.downcase.start_with? "cheese!" }

puts "Page title is #{driver.title}"
driver.quit
```

If that is not an option you can try the suggestion from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688435/how-can-i-implement-wait-for-page-to-load-in-selenium-2) though it would require some Javascript on top of the Ruby/Rails.

It seems that `wait.until` is being/has been phased out. The new suggested process it to look for the page to have an element you know will be there:

```
expect(page).to have_selector '#main_div_id'
```

Comment: I used the example from Selenium docs you linked to and this worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: how can i wait for an pop up ad on a site and click the "X" element on it to exit from the ad.
my code is not waiting until the ad loads and giving me the error that: "element not interactable (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError)"
can some one help me with how to wait until my element loads and click on the found element pls?
@ScottJShea

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understand webdriver, you dont need to wait for page loads because WebDriver has a [blocking API](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q%3a_WebDriver_fails_to_find_elements_/_Does_not_block_on_page_loa) but you can sure set a page load timeout.

```
driver.manage.timeouts.page_load = 10 # seconds
```

Answer (score 3):

So in Ruby, whenever you use `get` to open a URL, the ruby script proceeds ONLY when the page completely loads.

So in your case you would simply do :-

```
driver.get url
```

Comment: I thought so too, but Webdriver documentation states - "Dependent on several factors, including the OS/Browser combination, WebDriver may or may not wait for the page to load. In some circumstances, WebDriver may return control before the page has finished, or even started, loading. To ensure robustness, you need to wait for the element(s) to exist in the page using Explicit and Implicit Waits."

Comment: From my experience, Webdriver definitely does not always wait for everything to load, especially when loading content using AJAX. Definitely use a wait.

Comment: I can confirm with ajax loaded data that a wait is absolutely required.

Answer (score 2):

That's not needed with WebDriver anymore.

WebElement click() and Actions click() both "wait for page load" if needed automatically.

You can use imclicit and explicit (in this order) wait instead (described at seleniumhq) if you need to wait for some ajax content for instance.

Answer (score 1):

There have been instances where either AJAX or CSS changes caused my tests to fail at times. I added these methods to my static driver instance so that I can have the test wait for certain conditions if needed. (c#)

TimedWait in the WaitForCssChange Method is basically just a `Threading.Thread.Sleep` This is not the most beautiful way I guess, but it works well for my needs.

For Ajax wait:

```
 public static void WaitForAjax()
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(25));
        wait.Until(d => (bool)(d as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0"));
    }
```

For CSS Changes:

```
public static void  WaitForCssChange(IWebElement element, string value)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
           if(element.GetAttribute("style").Contains(value) || counter > 50)
           {
               break;
           }
           TimedWait(20);
           counter++;
        }
    }
```